# Same functions different structures

Tags: go

I have two separate packages, in which the struct implements the same functions. In fact, most of the function's code are also identical For e.g.

```
package #1

type T1 struct {
  Message string
  ID string
}

func (t *T1) GetID() {
   return t.ID
}

func (t *T1) GetRedisID() {
   return "t1" // hardcoded
}

package #2

type T2 struct {
  ClassName   string
  ID string
}

func (t *T2) GetID() {
   return t.ID
}

func (t *T2) GetRedisID() {
   return "t2" // hardcoded
}
```

I would like to keep the functions common between these two packages. What would be the options to do this in Go.

I cannot use interfaces here, because I want to access the variables also within the structure and keep the function common. I do not want to reimplement the function in both the files.

Comment: @JimB you always beat me to it :)

Comment: I don't think this is actually a duplicate, because the answers differ.  The linked question is about accepting two types with the same method (answer: use an interface).  This OP seems to be asking how to take a single implementation and have it apply to multiple structures, which would require embedding.

Comment: @JimB I just looked into that answer. The issue here is, I want to keep the code common and access the variable within the structure. For e.g. "t.ID". I don't see how that can be done with interfaces!

Comment: @Hugo you need a BaseT struct that has an ID string and a GetID() string method.  Look for embedding.

Comment: Example of that embedding: https://play.golang.org/p/SHayk46PVP

Comment: @Hugo: that's why I didn't mark it right away until you agreed ;) Are you just trying to factor out the `GetID()` method and the `ID` field?

Comment: @JimB yea, my bad :). I was too fast to first think I got the answer. I have quite a few functions which are very similar between these two structures. I will play with embedded structs and see, before I confirm. One issue is, the location of the ID field are different in these two structures. Let me check.

Comment: In the embedded version, the location is the same for both.  It can be accessed as `t1.ID` and `t2.ID`, or if you want to be explicit, `t1.Common.ID` and `t2.Common.ID` (this is only necessary if you need to disambiguate the field from another in the structure).  In the printf, is shows it as a substructure (which is what it actually is), but embedding "promotes" all fields and methods of the embedded structure to available on the parent structure.  Some references: http://www.hydrogen18.com/blog/golang-embedding.html, https://www.goinggo.net/2014/05/methods-interfaces-and-embedded-types.html